# CentOS 7 Cannot Find Module 'parse-server'

Tags: centos7, parse-server

I've been trying these days to run a local parse server in VirtualBox (with CentOS 7, red-had_x64) with the parse-server-example repository. The problem is that this error appears always when I do `sudo npm start`.

```html
> parse-server-example@1.4.0 start /root/Documentos/github/parse-server-example
> node index.js

module.js:478
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'parse-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/Documentos/github/parse-server-example/index.js:5:44)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)

npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.4.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server-example@1.4.0 start script 'node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the parse-server-example package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs parse-server-example
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-server-example
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/Documentos/github/parse-server-example/npm-debug.log
```

I also have been reading about this, and try the `sudo npm install parse-server` and also `npm install parse-server` and both of them give me this:

```html
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-tracing@0.15.0: The `apollo-tracing` package is no longer part of Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#tracing for details
npm WARN deprecated apollo-cache-control@0.14.0: The functionality provided by the `apollo-cache-control` package is built in to `apollo-server-core` starting with Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#cachecontrol for details.
npm WARN deprecated graphql-extensions@0.15.0: The `graphql-extensions` API has been removed from Apollo Server 3. Use the plugin API instead: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @parse/simple-mailgun-adapter@1.1.0: Package no longer supported. Use at your own risk. Find a list of supported e-mail adapters at https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server#email-verification-and-password-reset
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.19.2: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN deprecated lsof@0.1.0: No longer maintained
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.0: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@4.0.8: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 7.20.3 -> 7.21.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.21.0
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@7.21.0 to update!
npm notice
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /root/Documentos/github/parse-server-example/node_modules/kerberos
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! make: se ingresa al directorio `/root/Documentos/github/parse-server-example/node_modules/kerberos/build'
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/src/kerberos.o
npm ERR! make: se sale del directorio `/root/Documentos/github/parse-server-example/node_modules/kerberos/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.7.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.5 found at "/usr/bin/python"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.7.0/node-v16.7.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.7.0/node-v16.7.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.7.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.7.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! (node:3831) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/root/Documentos/github/parse-server-example/node_modules/kerberos/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.7.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.7.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.7.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/root/Documentos/github/parse-server-example/node_modules/kerberos',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=gnu++14’
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos/src/kerberos.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /root/Documentos/github/parse-server-example/node_modules/kerberos
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.7.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-24T00_20_33_671Z-debug.log
```

The versions of my node.js when I put `node -v`

```html
v16.7.0
```

And my mongoDB version with `mongo -version` is:

```html
MongoDB shell version v4.4.8
Build Info: {
    "version": "4.4.8",
    "gitVersion": "83b8bb8b6b325d8d8d3dfd2ad9f744bdad7d6ca0",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "rhel70",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Comment: try just `npm install` inside the parse-server-example folder

Comment: I tried, and the output still the same. I notice that doing the "ls" command to see the files, only like the half of the files are downloaded with git clone.

Comment: It looks it is not being able to install this module `kerberos` for your OS. Maybe it would be good first you find a solution for that.

Comment: I found it, the problema was the version of nodeJS. I was using an unstable version, but I fixed that and now it runs well.